# Find the number of ways of constructing $8$ using three distinct integers from {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Tags: permutations

In this particular example, order does matter. But at the moment, the only method I can think of is to tediously list them out.

$0+1+7$

$0+2+6$

And so on. But I am thinking that there is surely a better way in general, especially when there are more and more numbers.

Comment: Start from the largest value, $8$.  How many ways can you make $8$ using that?  Next, consider $7$:  How many ways can you make $8$ using that $7$?  And so on.

Comment: Hint: stars and bars.

Comment: @BarryCipra I thought of the stars and bars method. But how can we ensure that the three integers are distinct? We can construct 8 stars and add in two bars, but what is to prevent a $1+1+6$ scenario occurring?

Comment: @Trogdor, ah, you're right. I missed that crucial condition. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to list the $5$ ways to do it with $3$ distinct numbers in ascending order, now each of these can be permuted in $6$ different ways, so there are $\color{red}{30}$ ways in toto.

Answer (score 0):

Choose 0 as the first number, like you did. Notice that the numbers almost move towards the ends of the set. For instance the 2nd number will get to 7 while the 3rd number will get to 1. So, for each 1st number, you can easily see the number of combinations. Just remember to ignore duplicates.

Comment: Or just use a computer:  *Mathematica* instantly gives $\{\{8\},\{7,1\},\{6,2\},\{6,1,1\},\{5,3\},\{5,2,1\},\{5,1,1,1\},\{4,4\},\{4,3,1\},\{4,2,2\},\{4,2,1,1\},\{4,1,1,1,1\},\{
   3,3,2\},\{3,3,1,1\},\{3,2,2,1\},\{3,2,1,1,1\},\{3,1,1,1,1,1\},\{2,2,2,2\},\{2,2,2,1,1\},\{2,2,1,1,1,1\},\{2,1,1,1,1,1
   ,1\},\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}\}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I think you're solving a different problem than what the OP is asking.